# Python re.sub: ignore backreferences in the replacement string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to replace a pattern with a string. The string is given in a variable. It might, of course, contains '\1', and it should not be interpreted as a backreference - but simply as \1.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I don't control what's in the variable given to me, which contains the replacement string. I can of course, look for \1 type patterns, and replace them with \\1. But that's messy, and ugly.

Comment: That's why there's a method that does that for you: [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape)

Comment: @max I changed my answer completely, maybe my thinking about what is going on there helps you (At least I learned a lot from your question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The previous answer using `re.escape()` would escape too much, and you would get undesirable backslashes in the replacement and the replaced string.

It seems like in Python only the backslash needs escaping in the replacement string, thus something like this could be sufficient:

```
replacement = replacement.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/l4Fg9):

```
import re

x = r'hai! \1 <ops> $1 \' \x \\'
print "want to see: "
print x

print "getting: "
print re.sub(".(.).", x, "###")
print "over escaped: "
print re.sub(".(.).", re.escape(x), "###")
print "could work: "
print re.sub(".(.).", x.replace("\\", "\\\\"), "###")
```

Output:

```
want to see: 
hai! \1 <ops> $1 \' \x \\
getting: 
hai! # <ops> $1 \' \x \
over escaped: 
hai\!\ \1\ \<ops\>\ \$1\ \\'\ \x\ \\
could work: 
hai! \1 <ops> $1 \' \x \\
```

Comment: OK you are correct, re.escape is the wrong choice here, it would be correct if the escaped string should be used as regex, but in the replacement string, only the `\1` ... needs to be escaped. So understanding this I would restrict the replacement a bit more to only backslashes followed by digits like this `re.sub(r"\\(?=\d)", r"\\\\", x)` (it makes no difference in your example, again not sure why, escaping is sometimes a mystery to me)

Comment: `re.sub(r"\\", r"\\\\", x)` is a bit overkill here. You could just do `x.replace("\\", "\\\\")` as a simple doubling of any backslashes doesn't need regular expressions. @stema, you only *need* to double backslashes that are followed by a digit or another backslash but doubling other backslashes doesn't matter and makes the code simpler.

Comment: @Duncan you agree that I only need to double backslashes followed by a digit, but downvote my answer because its not escaping enough??? Can you please explain to me what is not escaped that should be?

Comment: @Duncan, indeed, I updated my answer to include your correction.

Answer (score 5):

Due to comments I thought quite a while about this and tried it out. Helped me a lot to increase my understanding about escaping, so I changed my answer nearly completely that it could be useful for later readers.

NullUserException gave you just the short version, I try to explain it a bit more. And thanks to the critical reviews of Qtax and Duncan, this answer is hopefully now correct and helpful.

The backslash has a special meaning, its the escape character in strings, that means the backslash and the following character form an escape sequence that is translated to something else when something is done with the string. This "something is done" is already the creation of the string. So if you want to use `\` literally you need to escape it. This escape character is the backslash itself.

So as start some examples for a better understanding what happens. I print additionally the ASCII codes of the characters in the string to hopefully increase the understandability of what happens.

```
s = "A\1\nB"
print s
print [x for x in s]
print [hex(ord(x)) for x in s]
```

is printing

```
A
B
['A', '\x01', '\n', 'B']
['0x41', '0x1', '0xa', '0x42']
```

So while I typed `\` and `1` in the code, `s` does not contain those two characters, it contains the ASCII character `0x01` which is "Start of heading". Same for the `\n`, it translated to `0x0a` the Linefeed character.

Since this behaviour is not always wanted, raw strings can be used, where the escape sequences are ignored.

```
s = r"A\1\nB"
print s
print [x for x in s]
print [hex(ord(x)) for x in s]
```

I just added the `r` before the string and the result is now

```
A\1\nB
['A', '\\', '1', '\\', 'n', 'B']
['0x41', '0x5c', '0x31', '0x5c', '0x6e', '0x42']
```

All characters are printed as I typed them.

This is the situation we have. Now there is the next thing.

There can be the situation that a string should be passed to a regex to be found literally, so every character that has a special meaning within a regex (e.g. +*$[.) needs to escaped, therefore there is a special function `re.escape` that does this job.

But for this question this is the wrong function, because the string should not be used within a regex, but as the replacement string for `re.sub`.

**So new situation:**

A raw string including escape sequences should be used as replacement string for `re.sub`. `re.sub` will also handle the escape sequences, but with a small, but important, difference to the handling before:  `\n` is still translated to `0x0a` the Linefeed character, but the transition of `\1` has changed now! It will be replaced by the content of the capturing group 1 of the regex in `re.sub`.

```
s = r"A\1\nB"
print re.sub(r"(Replace)" ,s , "1 Replace 2")
```

And the result is

```
1 AReplace
B 2
```

The `\1` has been replaced with the content of the capturing group and `\n` with the LineFeed character.

The important point is, you have to understand this behaviour and now you have two possiblities to my opinion (and I am not going to judge which one is the correct one)

1. The creator is unsure about the string behaviour and if he inputs `\n` then he wants a newline. In this case use this to just escape the `\` that are followed by a digit.

   ```
   OnlyDigits = re.sub(r"(Replace)" ,re.sub(r"(\\)(?=\d)", r"\\\\", s) , "1 Replace 2")
   print OnlyDigits
   print [x for x in OnlyDigits]
   print [hex(ord(x)) for x in OnlyDigits
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   1 A\1
   B 2
   ['1', ' ', 'A', '\\', '1', '\n', 'B', ' ', '2']
   ['0x31', '0x20', '0x41', '0x5c', '0x31', '0xa', '0x42', '0x20', '0x32']
   ```
2. The creator nows exactly what he is doing and if he would have wanted a newline, he would have typed `\0xa`. In this case escape all

   ```
   All = re.sub(r"(Replace)" ,re.sub(r"(\\)", r"\\\\", s) , "1 Replace 2")
   print All
   print [x for x in All]
   print [hex(ord(x)) for x in All]
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   1 A\1\nB 2
   ['1', ' ', 'A', '\\', '1', '\\', 'n', 'B', ' ', '2']
   ['0x31', '0x20', '0x41', '0x5c', '0x31', '0x5c', '0x6e', '0x42', '0x20', '0x32']
   ```

Comment: Got it, thanks. I guess it would also mess up '\n', so if someone passed me a string that they meant to include newline expressed as '\n', I'm out of luck. But that's not a big deal.

Comment: @max: If someone wants a newline, they pass a one-byte newline, not a 2-byte escape sequence (unless of course they are confused).

Comment: @Qtax would you mind giving a more correct answer then? I am not sure if I understand your concerns.

Comment: -1, not completely right. This will escape too much and you will get literal backslashes in the replaced string that were not in the original replacement. Example: http://ideone.com/biheB

Comment: @Duncan I changed the formatting of my output, I missed that it interpreted the backslashes instead of just printing it, was this your problem, or is there another one?

Comment: Try Qtax's example with your escaping: `print re.sub(".(.).", re.sub(r"\\(?=\d)", r"\\\\", s), "###")` s ends with 4 characters `\r\n` but the substitution will end with two characters: carriage return + linefeed. That's why you need to double the backslashes whether or not they are followed by a digit.

Comment: @Duncan I am not sure if this is wrong behaviour, the problem with the `\1` was that the `re.sub` interpreted it and inserted the first capturing group. To my opinion it should be OK when a `\n` is printed as a new line and not as `\n`. this is not a problem regarding the `re.sub`.

Comment: why should re.sub interpreting `\r` be any less wrong than re.sub interpreting `\1`? If the original code was `re.sub("\[filename\]", replacement, s)` and the user supplied the string `r"C:\random\123.txt"` you want to stop either of those backslashes being interpreted.

Comment: @Duncan I think `re.sub` is not interpreting `\r` its just searching for any backreferences, e.g. the `\1`. The `\r` is interpreted by the `print` that outputs the resulting string.

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub `repl can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. That is, \n is converted to a single newline character, \r is converted to a carriage return, and so forth. Unknown escapes such as \j are left alone. Backreferences, such as \6, are replaced with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern.`

Comment: @JohnMachin ahh yes yes.. if the string passed to me was initialized as x = 'abc\n', it doesn't mean that it actually contains '\' and 'n'! I got confused :)

Comment: @Qtax hopefully my improved answer is now good enough that you are able to remove your downvote.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks to your critical comments I thought a while about this issue and escaping is a lot clearer to me, now. I came to the conclusion, that I do not know enough about the the OPs situation to be able to judge which behaviour is the correct one for the OP. So I tried to explain what happens here and let the OP judge what he really wants. I hope my new answer will be good enough that you remove your downvote.

Comment: re.sub(r"(\\)", r"\\\\", s) solves my problem, thank you so much!