# Replace the href value in a hyperlink with a Windows file path?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the sub method and regular expressions in Python to search for all instances of `<xref href="8832">` and replace with a Windows File Path: `<xref href="3.1 First Level\3.1.1 Second Level\3.1.1.2 Third Level.dita">` but it keeps failing on the second to last line (regex_replace = ...). Here is my code:

```
matches = re.search(r'<xref(\s*)href="(\d+)">', html)
if matches:
    topicid = matches.group(2)
    windowsfilepath = '3.1 First Level\3.1.1 Second Level\3.1.1.2 Third Level.txt'
    regex_search = r'<xref(\s*)href="' + re.escape(topicid) + r'">'
    regex_replace = r'<xref href="'+ re.escape(windowsfilepath) + r'">'
    html = re.sub(regex_search,regex_replace,html)
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with escaping the backslashes and/or periods in `windowsfilepath`, but I've tried using re.escape() and the text is never replaced.

Comment: Why a -1, is there something that isn't clear in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your `windowsfilepath` in extra double quotes you should be able to simply replace all matches with `re.sub()` like this:

```
windowsfilepath = '"3.1 First Level\3.1.1 Second Level\3.1.1.2 Third Level.txt"'
new_html = re.sub(r'(?<=\<xref href\=)("\d+")', windowsfilepath, html)
```

EDIT:

Apparently, `\3` is transformed into an [End-of-Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Text_character) character. If you try to escape (`\`) like this `\\3` it is treated by `re.sub()` as a [backreference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) (which, in this case, doesn't exists and the code fails). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441984/python-re-sub-ignore-backreferences-in-the-replacement-string) they proposed to add an `.replace('\\', '\\\\')` method to the replacement string in `re.sub()`, then you'll end up with a `\\` instead of `TEX`.

I would suggest to try a slash `/` instead of a backslash `\`, that should work on windows [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes#176395).

Here is the modified code:

```
windowsfilepath = '"3.1 First Level/3.1.1 Second Level/3.1.1.2 Third Level.txt"'
new_html = re.sub(r'(?<=\<xref href\=)("\d+")', windowsfilepath, html)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but now the link looks like this: <xref href="3.1 First LevelETX.1.1 Second LevelETX.1.1.2 Third Level.txt">  The ETX character is bolded in SublimeText, not sure what it represents.